# Armstrong Program goes until 1000, but not higher. What to do to go higher?

Tags: java

I have with Armstrong program in java. So the program shall check if the numbers between a interval, which are given by somebody.(Example: Please gíve a lower number: 100; Please give a higher class: 1700; And the program should give out all number, which are Armstrong in this interval.)

Problem is, that the program only checks if Armstrong numbers are til 1000, but not any higher.

One line got me curious then, which is: `sum = sum + (r*r*r);` 
So if i change it to `(r*r*r*r)`, it only shows Armstrong numbers over 1000 and not below 1000. 
Any ideas what´s wrong with it and how to change it?

Here is the code:

```
static boolean isArmstrong(int number) {
    boolean isArmNumber = false;
    int sum = 0;
    int tempNum = number; 
    while (tempNum > 0) {
        int r = tempNum % 10;
        sum = sum + (r*r*r);
        tempNum = tempNum / 10;         
    }
    if (sum == number) {
        isArmNumber = true;
    }
    return isArmNumber;     
}
```

Comment: Show us the code so that we can see what's wrong.!!

Comment: Whats stopping you front going higher? An error? Are you using a recursive function that's throwing a StackOverflow?

Comment: How in the world do you expect anyone to answer if you don't provide your code to see where you might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sum = sum + (r*r*r);` so your code finds 153, 370, 371 and 407 as valid Armstrong numbers.
If you want to check the higher numbers you have to change your calculation to `(r*r*r*r)` and so on, according to the length of the input number.

Replace `sum = sum + (r*r*r);` with:

```
 int tmp = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i < String.valueOf(number).length(); i++) {
       tmp = tmp * r;
 }
 sum = sum + tmp;
```

Comment: But that´s the problem. I need all the numbers who are from an interval . For example: i have the nubmbers from  100 to 1700 and the progrogramm should outpout all the armstrong numbers from 100 to 1700 but where it´s going, the programm only outputs armstrong numbers till 1000 (r*r*r) or all armstrong numbers higher then 1000(r*r*r*r). And I want them to be all togheter and not seperate.

Comment: then it doens´t do anything tbh. I only can out in the lower number and the upper number, then the programm doens´t output anything. it´s just blanck then

Comment: Ooopsi, `int tmp = 1;` instead of `int tmp = r;` My fault, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did this fix your problem? If so:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yep, it did help. Thanks again^^